# Safari 13 draw only the first frame of a video on canvas

Tags: canvas, safari, drawimage

I'm trying to paint the current frame of a  on a canvas but Safari 13 only paints the first frame… sometimes.Somebody knows any workarround

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

update();

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 230,125)
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 230,125);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

```html
<p>Play the video and then click on the canvas to paint</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width='240' height='135' style="border: solid;"></canvas>
<video id="video" width='240' height='135' autoplay controls loop src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: The easiest workaround would be not to use Safari 13...

Comment: I just tested on Safari 13.1.1 and that snippet runs fine